# How to check if it's edit.php & post_type is set?

Tags: wp-admin, actions, post-type

I wanted to use css codes on certain post type with certain post status so i'm looking for a correct conditionals to use.

How can i detect this if it's edit.php &  post_status = draft& post_type = food?

Example: domain.com/wp-admin/**edit.php**?***post_status=draft***&***post_type=food***

Tried the code below but it didnt work.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['post_status']) && $_REQUEST['post_status'] == 'custom' ) { 
   echo '<style>tr.status-custom{ display: none; }</style>';
   }
```

PS: I basically want to hide posts (tr.status-draft) with drafts or any custom statuses using css so it doesn't appear on "all post" but appears when the Their designated post_status is set. So i basically can't do it with css alone because they will also be hidden even if the post_status action is set. So i really need a correct conditionals to use.

Answer (score 1):

Post type is reflected in `body` as class. It is `.post-type-post` for posts, `.post-type-product` for WooCommerce products and must be `.post-type-food` in your case. So, you can use css rule like that to detect certain post type:

```
body.post-type-food #titlediv input {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

Post status is reflected only in TinyMCE editor classes, as `.post-status-draft`. You can use it as follows:

```
body#tinymce.post-status-draft {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I basically want to hide posts (tr.status-draft) with drafts or any custom statuses using css so it doesn't appear on "all post" but appears when the Their designated post_status is set. So i basically can't do it with css alone because they will also be hidden even if the post_status action is set.

Comment: The word "hide" is absent in your question. Otherwise I would tell you that it is impossible via css.

Comment: Yea, i was actually looking for a conditionals to display my css code. Sorry i have updated my post. Thnks

Comment: I do not understand your intentions. Please show the screenshot of the page /edit.php?post_status=draft&post_type=food pointing the elements you want to hide.